# Problems With Duplicated AI

Tags: unity, ai

I am having a problem with making duplicates of my AI. When one is within range, it performs normally. If two are in range, then they both freeze up. The AI are direct duplicates of each other. I don't know what causes this. Code 
below:

Any help is seriously appreciated. Thank you.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class NavMeshAI : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform player;
public Transform head;
public Animator anim;
public bool pursuing = false;
public NavMeshAgent navComponent;
public Transform enemy;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    navComponent = this.gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position;
    direction.y = 0;

    float angle = Vector3.Angle (direction, head.up);

    if (Vector3.Distance (player.position, this.transform.position) < 10 && (angle < 360 || pursuing)) {

        pursuing = true;
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (direction), 0.1f);

        anim.SetBool ("isIdle", false);
        if (direction.magnitude > 2) {
            this.transform.Translate (0, 0, 0.05f);
            anim.SetBool ("isWalking", true);
            anim.SetBool ("isAttacking", false);
            if (pursuing == true) {
                navComponent.SetDestination (player.position);
            }
            } else {
            anim.SetBool ("isAttacking", true);
            anim.SetBool ("isWalking", false);
        }
    } else {
        anim.SetBool ("isIdle", true);
        anim.SetBool ("isWalking", false);
        anim.SetBool ("isAttacking", false);
        pursuing = false;
        navComponent.SetDestination (enemy.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of public variables that look like they need to be initialised for this code to work. Is there an initialisattion routine for these objects?

Comment: I’m guessing they are assigned in the inspector. Perhaps a screenshot of the inspector of each object would help.

Comment: By "they freeze up" do you mean the animation fails to work, or that they don't move toward the player, or both?